# default attributes & pthread_create() POSIX C linux

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

Could anybody explain step by step why such arguments ( `NULL` pointer(s) ) when calling `pthread_create` like this:

```
pthread_create(&id_thread1,NULL,thread1,NULL);
```

result in default attributes for the `thread1` ?

I know that `pthread.h` file is a key factor here.
But unfortunately I do not understand why; the code is way too sophisticated to me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature to [**`pthread_create`**](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) is:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

The second argument is a `pthread_attr_t*` pointer.  This allows you to set [various attributes of the thread](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_attr_init.3.html), such as scheduling policy or thread stack-size, using a `pthread_attr_t` object.  If `attr` is `NULL` then default attributes are used.

The fourth argument is simply a `void*` pointer that can point to any arbitrary user data to be passed to `start_routine` when the thread begins.  If `arg` is `NULL` then a null pointer is passed.

Comment: I've included links to the man pages, but I'm not sure what sort of justification you're looking for. This is simply the way the POSIX designers decided to write the `pthread` API. It provides a way to set thread attributes, and pass arbitrary user data to the new thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need to know exactly where does pthread.h (or some other file)  state that when `pthread_attr_t* attr` is `NULL` then default attributes are used and why ?

Comment: The man page I linked to says `If attr is NULL, then the thread is created with default attributes.`  See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html

Comment: The *standard* states that. The header has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thanks again! I do understand that there are standards and man pages, but what happens when the code goes to compiler ? I mean, how does it technically happen that I write such call with second NULL as a argument and then such attributes are used ? I see that `pthread` API has been mentioned, could somebody say a bit more about it? It's really important to me. :)

Comment: @user1991012 because in the implementation of the pthread function there's some stuff like `if (arg == NULL) { /* use default attributes */ }`...

Comment: @user1991012 In the source code of the pthread library. You probably don't have its source code. If you're interested in it, download the source code of the C library you're using.

Comment: somewhere in there ? http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=tree;f=nptl;h=d0ce23d37e9b77d6ff82ffdee0f7a1f8f137aa41;hb=HEAD

Comment: @user1991012: Lines 454-457 in nptl/pthread_create.c (http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/pthread_create.c;h=4fe0755079e5491ad360c3b4f26c182543a0bd6e;hb=HEAD#l457). The `default_attr` is defined on lines 437-441; all unmentioned fields are initialized to zero. For example, the stack size defaults to a library internal value (`__default_stacksize`) if it is zero; see lines 359-361 of nptl/allocatestack.c (http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=nptl/allocatestack.c;h=31c88291ae91b3e940a8f41da8ff49a44038ec6d;hb=HEAD#l361).

Comment: these are lines 437-441: `static const struct pthread_attr default_attr = {
   /* Just some value > 0 which gets rounded to the nearest page size.  */     .guardsize = 1,  };` and I can't see where or what `.guardsize,` means ...

Answer (score 0):

> [...] why such parameteres [...] result in default attributes for the thread1?

Because the pthread specifications require that this be the case if `NULL` is passed in as an **argument** (and not "parametere") of this particular function.

Comment: But I was asked about justification in code ... and I couldn't find it ... So the answer is that "man page says so" ?

Comment: @user1991012 Yes, basically it is.